# How to stop endless scroll in my app?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I am going to make website app and load feed on my first page but the problem is the scrolling is endless, how to stop this? The scrolling is endless so I want to stop it.

```
    public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private RecyclerView listView;

    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    private FeedAdapter adapter;
    private FeedService service;
    private FeedModel model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(null != actionBar)
        {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }

        model = new FeedModel();
        adapter = new FeedAdapter(model);
        service = FeedService.create(model);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeLayout);

        listView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        model.subscribe(onDataChangedListener);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(onRefreshListener);

        service.fetchOlder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        model.unSubscribe(onDataChangedListener);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(null);

    }

    FeedModel.OnDataChangedListener onDataChangedListener = new FeedModel.OnDataChangedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFetchedAndAddedToTop(int count)
        {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFetchedAndAddedToBottom(int count)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                adapter.setFooterEnabled(false);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh()
        {
            service.fetchNewer();
        }
    };


    FeedAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new FeedAdapter.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view)
        {
            int position = listView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            FeedItem item = model.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());

            startActivity(intent);

//            System.out.println("Click: "+item.getTitle());
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop scrolling in two ways

1. If you know how many items are refreshing for every refresh you done then make a condition to stop calling refresh when you get less items than actual.
2. You can simply make a condition to stop refreshing list when you don't get data from earlier refresh.

Hope this Helpful..

@Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

To stop endless scrolling apply a condition.
For example for every scroll 20 results are fetched and added to the list. Then you can apply a condition

```
if(lastFetchedItemCount!=0&&lastFetchedItemCount%20==0){
//enable scrolling
}
else{
//disable scrolling
}
```